# What determines the color of a Force-User's Force Lightning? (Canon or Legends)

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

We've seen multiple occasions of Force Users using Force-Lightning of different colors but never is it explained anywhere what causes those colors for those people. Examples below.

Darth Sidious - Violet/Indigo/Purple

Darth Tenebrous/Darth Maul - Red

Plo Koon - Yellow

Luke Skywalker - Green

Jaina Solo - Black

Comment: I don't think there is a real anserw beside "because it's cool". Canon-wise the color is always blue-ish ( or purple-ish when Sidious want to be more badass ), meanwhile in Legend... meh, everyone do whatever he thinks it's cooler.

Comment: Could you give pictures or other references to where this is evident, as far as I'm aware, force lighting is force lighting (there is no difference per user of it.) Also could you give an example of where Plo Koon used force lighting (I don't recall any time he uses lighting)? :)